# Add data to objects via cloud code

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In Cloud code, I create a function that get the users, and another function that add specific values to that user objects.

The problem is, that in Android we get the users objects, but without the specific values that was added.

When i copy the same code to the JS file in the client side, it's works perfect. I get all the objects with all the specific values that was added to them.

I attached the code
Someone know what the problem is?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getAllPeople", function (request, response) {
    var currentUser = request.user;
    var numberToSkip = request.params.numberToSkip || 0;
    var isMale = request.params.isMale;
    var latitude = request.params.latitude || 32.08; //Tel Aviv
    var longitude = request.params.longitude || 34.78;
    var parseGeoPoint = new Parse.GeoPoint({latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude});

    var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    var queryObject = new Parse.Query(User);

    queryObject.skip(numberToSkip).limit(100)
        .equalTo('isCheckIn', true)
        .equalTo('isMale', isMale)
        //.notEqualTo('objectId', currentUser.id)
        .near('location', parseGeoPoint)
        .notEqualTo('checkInPlace', null)
        .include('checkInPlace')
        .find({
            success: function (usersInCheckIn) {
                checkUserSend(currentUser, usersInCheckIn).then(function (results) {
                        response.success(results);
                });
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        });
});

function checkUserSend(currentUser, usersInCheckIn) {
    var Matching = Parse.Object.extend("Matching");
    var queryObject = new Parse.Query(Matching);
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();

    queryObject
        .equalTo('sendUser', currentUser)
        .include('sendUser')
        .find({
            success: function (results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var current = {};
                    current.receivedUser = results[i].get('receivedUser');
                    current.isMatching = results[i].get('isMatching');
                    current.isRejected = results[i].get('isRejected');
                    for (var j = 0; j < usersInCheckIn.length; j++) {
                        if (usersInCheckIn[j].id == current.receivedUser.id) {
                            usersInCheckIn[j].sendWink = true;
                            usersInCheckIn[j].isMatching = current.isMatching;
                            usersInCheckIn[j].isRejected = current.isRejected;
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log(usersInCheckIn);
                promise.resolve(usersInCheckIn);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        });
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: no error. i get all the users objects, but without the values "sendWink" "isMatching" "isRejected"

Comment: it has been returning promise without waiting of `queryObject` response

Comment: you can show me how the code should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `return` statement and add `response.success(usersInCheckIn);` on sucess of `queryObject` `find()`

```
function checkUserSend(currentUser, usersInCheckIn) {
var Matching = Parse.Object.extend("Matching");
var queryObject = new Parse.Query(Matching);
var promise = new Parse.Promise();

queryObject
    .equalTo('sendUser', currentUser)
    .include('sendUser')
    .find({
        success: function (results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var current = {};
                current.receivedUser = results[i].get('receivedUser');
                current.isMatching = results[i].get('isMatching');
                current.isRejected = results[i].get('isRejected');
                for (var j = 0; j < usersInCheckIn.length; j++) {
                    if (usersInCheckIn[j].id == current.receivedUser.id) {
                        usersInCheckIn[j].sendWink = true;
                        usersInCheckIn[j].isMatching = current.isMatching;
                        usersInCheckIn[j].isRejected = current.isRejected;
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log(usersInCheckIn);
           // promise.resolve(usersInCheckIn);
            response.success(usersInCheckIn);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not working.. on the Android side we don't get the "sendWink" "isMatching" and "isRejected" on the response object..